# Equivalent condition for compact support

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to prove following statement(if it's correct):

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function. Show that
> $$f \text{ has compact support} \iff \exists \ p\in \mathbb{R} : f(x) = 0 \text{   for all } |x|\ge p $$

According to the definitions we have $\text{supp}(f) = \overline{\{x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x) \not = 0 \}}$ and a set is compact if it's closed and bounded. First of all how can we be sure that $\text{supp}(f)$ is well-defined? I don't know how to put these definitions together. My main motivation for proposing that statement is $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)dx = \int_{-a}^{+a}f(x)dx$$ If $f(x)$ has compact support.

Comment: What sort of problems can you imagine with respect to well-definedness here?

Comment: @DanielFischer I don't know if always the closure of a set is defined.

Comment: The closure of a set is defined in topological spaces. How it is defined varies, but the definitions are equivalent (produce the same set).

Comment: @DanielFischer Okay, so the $\text{supp}(f)$ is well-defined. Thanks.

Comment: Am I wrong, or it should be $|x|>p?$ ($f$ doesn't seem required to be continuous)

Comment: @S.H.W I guess I do not understand your question.

Comment: @enzotib It doesn't matter due to $$\exists \ p\in \mathbb{R} : f(x) = 0 \text{   for all } |x|\ge p \iff \exists \ p\in \mathbb{R} : f(x) = 0 \text{   for all } |x|> p$$

Comment: @Gono, indeed, thank you

Comment: @Matematleta Sorry if I were unclear. My main question is $f \text{ has compact support} \iff \exists \ p\in \mathbb{R} : f(x) = 0 \text{   for all } |x|\ge p$          With the given definitions for support of function and compact set.

Comment: @S.H.W Yes, now I see. Your question was clear, I just did not get it initially. The answer seems to give you what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint for $=>$

By Heine-Borel, compactness in $\mathbb{R}$ is equivalent to the set being closed and bounded.

Hint for $<=$

Once again, use the Heine-Borel theorem. Note that the support is already closed by definition!

A comment on your motivational statement: Note that this only holds for sufficiently large $a$

Comment: Would you elaborate, please? I've accepted as definition that compact support means 
$A = \overline{\{x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x) \not = 0 \}}$
 is bounded and closed. How this implies that $\exists \ p\in \mathbb{R} : f(x) = 0 \text{   for all } |x|\ge p$ ?

Comment: Compactness implies that $A$ is bounded. Thus, at some distance from the origin, $f(x) \neq 0$ does not happen any more. Hence $f(x)=0$ for $|x|$ sufficiently large

Comment: So we can say $\overline{B} \text{ is bounded} \iff B \text{ is bounded}$?

Comment: Yes, because if $x_{n} \rightarrow x$ then $d(x_{n},0) \rightarrow d(x,0)$ for some metric $d$